# how to send valid JSON in CURL Ansible

Tags: git, ansible

I am using this task to get some specific values from github using ansible task.

```
- name: Register evercam-media local commit hash
  local_action:
    shell
    chdir={{local_media_dir}}
    git log --pretty='["%h", "%an", "%ae", "%ad", "%s"]' | head -1
  register: local_commit_info
```

which results into

```
"stdout": "[\"03d776b\", \"Azhar Malik\", \"azharmalik02@gmail.com\", \"Thu Dec 5 16:29:08 2019 +0500\", \"Added log on successful login\"]", 
"stdout_lines": [
    "[\"03d776b\", \"Azhar Malik\", \"azharmalik02@gmail.com\", \"Thu Dec 5 16:29:08 2019 +0500\", \"Added log on successful login\"]"
]
```

And I am trying to send it to an endpoint using curl. which is failing because of invalid json. and I have no idea how I can send `stdout` to the endpoint I have tried this.

```
- name: Send deploy email
  shell: "curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:3000/v1/server/deployed -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{{ local_commit_info.stdout  | regex_replace('\"', \"'\") }}'"
```

which give invalid json.

```
fatal: [media.evercam.io]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": true, 
    "cmd": "curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:3000/v1/server/deployed -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '['03d776b', 'Azhar Malik', 'azharmalik02@gmail.com', 'Thu Dec 5 16:29:08 2019 +0500', 'Added log on successful login']'", 
    "delta": "0:00:00.437950", 
    "end": "2019-12-09 23:32:06.042709", 
    "invocation": {
```

How Can I convert the results of `git log --pretty='["%h", "%an", "%ae", "%ad", "%s"]' | head -1` into valid JSON? so It can be sent through CURL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved my problem.

```
- name: Register evercam-media local commit hash
  local_action:
    shell
    chdir={{local_media_dir}}
    git log --pretty='{"sha":"%h", "authorName":"%an", "authorEmail":"%ae", "commiterName":"%cn", "commiterEmail":"%ce", "authorUnixTimestamp":"%at", "commiterUnixTimestamp":"%ct", "subject":"%s", "branch":"%d", "deployType":"hotcode"}' | head -1
  register: local_commit_info

- set_fact:
    commit: "{{ local_commit_info.stdout|from_json }}"

- uri: 
    url: "https://app.herokuapp.com/v1/server/deployed"
    method: POST
    return_content: yes
    body_format: json
    body: "{{ commit }}"
    status_code: 201, 200
  register: result
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether Ansible is the way to go for what you're trying to achieve.

However, you can parse the stdout as json, [use a filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#filters-for-formatting-data).

Probably something along the lines of:

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ local_commit_info.stdout | from_json.commit }}"
```

-- edit --

use the [uri_module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/uri_module.html) instead of using shell with curl.

Comment: `"msg": "template error while templating string: no filter named 'from_json.commit'. String: {{ local_commit_info.stdout | from_json.commit }}"`

Comment: I didnt find your answer useful in any way but thanks